# Google Wave Server - command line client only?

Tags: google-wave

I understand that there is a version of the Google Wave server that one can install standalone on their own server.   However, my initial reading leads me to understand that there is no web client for this, only a command line client (at this point).

Can someone confirm that this is the case?

Also, if this IS THE CASE is there any current timeline when the web client might be available for the standalone server?

(please feel free to correct my understanding of any of the above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone confirm that this is the case?

Yes, there is only a CLI-client for Wave from Google at the moment.

> Also, if this IS THE CASE is there any current timeline when the web client might be available for the standalone server?

I don't think, that Google will release its Wave web client. Only the Wave protocol and the server implementation are free, the web client is not.

Answer (score -1):

[Wave installation](http://code.google.com/p/wave-protocol/wiki/Installation)

I guess there is an answer here?